How to install pyfanuc? Encountering errors with pip install from PyPI
I am currently working on a project that requires me to use the pyfanuc library, which is a Python package for communicating with FANUC Machine. I found the package on PyPI and tried to follow the installation instructions provided on this page: pyfanuc.
However, I am encountering an error during the installation process, and I haven't been able to resolve it. I have tried several approaches, including checking my Python version, updating pip. Despite these efforts, I continue to face the same issue.
Here is the specific error message I am receiving during the installation:
`Collecting pyfanuc
  Using cached pyfanuc-0.0.5-py3-none-any.whl (168 kB)
Collecting tomli
  Using cached tomli-2.0.1-py3-none-any.whl (12 kB)
Collecting pyfanuc
  Using cached pyfanuc-0.0.4-py3-none-any.whl (168 kB)
  Using cached pyfanuc-0.0.3-py3-none-any.whl (4.7 kB)
  Using cached pyfanuc-0.0.2-py3-none-any.whl (329 kB)
ERROR: Cannot install pyfanuc==0.0.2, pyfanuc==0.0.3, pyfanuc==0.0.4 and pyfanuc==0.0.5 because these package versions have conflicting dependencies.

The conflict is caused by:
    pyfanuc 0.0.5 depends on fwlipy
    pyfanuc 0.0.4 depends on fwlipy
    pyfanuc 0.0.3 depends on fwlipy
    pyfanuc 0.0.2 depends on fwlipy

To fix this you could try to:
1. loosen the range of package versions you've specified
2. remove package versions to allow pip attempt to solve the dependency conflict

ERROR: ResolutionImpossible: for help visit https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/topics/dependency-resolution/#dealing-with-dependency-conflicts`


Has anyone else encountered a similar problem with pyfanuc? If so, how did you resolve it? Are there any additional dependencies or steps that I might be missing?

Is this just from pip install pyfanuc, or are you running some other command?

just frompip install pyfanuc

What OS are you using? Also what's your Python version?

pyfanuc depends on fwlipy but there is no such package at PyPI: https://pypi.org/project/fwlipy/ — error 404. You cannot install the package. Actually fwlipy is a subpackage inside pyfanuc distribution and shouldn't be a dependency. Report the bug to the owner. Try installing it without dependencies: pip install --no-deps pyfanuc

Report the bug to: Lea Tonecja tonejca@ift.at.

im using windows 11 and my python version is 3.10.4

i just installing with this command pip install --no-deps pyfanuc  and appear the error is Import "pyfanuc" could not be resolved
